Header not printing for every page in Chrome-based browser
This is not a request for help but a possible solution for everybody who might encounter this problem.
I had a quite complex header that when printed would not appear from the second page onward.
Firefox displayed it correctly but not any Chromium-based browser.
After a couple of days fidgeting I finally found the issue was a lateral padding on the tables.
Simply changing
.outer-display { padding: 3pt; }

to
.outer-display { padding: 3pt 0; }

fixed the issue
